# Spacy - Identify Token in Pattern Matching

Tags: python, spacy

I would like to make a program that extract from a sentences two words, and I need to know if one of the word is the departure, and if the other is the arrival.

I tried to make a pattern and set the token type inside the custom extension attribute, for example for this sentence: `"I would like a London Paris train"`.

I created this pattern:

```
pattern = [
    {"POS":  "PROPN", "_": {"TYPE": "ARRIVAL"}},
    {"POS":  "PROPN", "_": {"TYPE": "DEPARTURE"}}
]
```

And I also created a custom_extension attribute inside my python code:

```
Token.set_extension('TYPE', default="", force=True)
```

My problem is that, if `TYPE` in my pattern doesn't match the default value, nothing is matched.

I would like to know if there is a better solution with Pattern Matching to identify matched tokens.

Thanks a lot by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is "semantic role labelling" and it's hard. You absolutely can't do this with just pattern matching.

The very simplest thing you can do that might work, which will work on your example, is to use spaCy's NER model to get all LOC or GPO entities, and assume the first one is the departure and the second one is the arrival. That'll be really brittle though.